# separate versioning for child project that depends on other projects

Tags: maven

I have `pom.xml` in the child project of the multimodule project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>Parent-POM</artifactId>
    <groupId>parent.package</groupId>
    <version>2.0.0-RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Service</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>parent.package</groupId>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

I want to have different versioning for the child project, but preserve the version for dependency packages. Basically I want this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>Parent-POM</artifactId>
    <groupId>parent.package</groupId>
    <version>2.0.0-RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Service</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>parent.package</groupId>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

How to achieve that?

If I specify `<version>` for `service` project it affects `${project.version}` of the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${parent.version}`.

This references the version of the parent.